# Grab the classname of nested HTML elements with Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, html, web-scraping, puppeteer

I am trying to get get all of the `td` elements that have a class name of `calendarCellRegularPast` I have tried multiple attempts with `page.$`, `page.$$`, `page.eval` and many others and cannot seem to get the proper element. I got the object at on point but was unable to parse it. I know that there is a way to do this but I am new to puppeteer and Javascript honestly and just cannot figure it out.

This is a calendar of scheduled work days and I am trying to get even further down and grab the date and time. I want to have that in a for loop though so I can grab all of the work times.

I don't need a fix to my code as I know its messy but I just need to know how to grab those elements

[image]

---

[image]

Here is some of my code so far, though it is messy as I was trying numerous things

```
 const el = await page.$("#scrollContainer > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(1)")
 const className = await el.getProperty('className')
```

---

```
 const getElm = async() => {
    try {
        const elm = await page.evaluate(()=> {
            let persons = [];
            const weekElm = document.querySelectorAll("#scrollContainer > table > tbody");
            
            document.querySelector("#scrollContainer > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(3)")


            console.log('\n\n\n', weekElm.length, '\n\n\n');
            try {
                console.log(weekElm);
            } catch (e) {
                console.error('could not log "weeksElm"');
            }
            
            for (let i = 2; i < weekElm.length; i++) {
                try {
                    const trd = weekElm[i];
                    console.log(trd);
                    const tr = document.querySelectorAll(`tr:nth-child${i+1}`)
                    persons.push(tr);
                    try {
                        console.log('\n\n\n', tr, '\n\n\n');
                    } catch (e) {
                        console.error('could not log "\\n\\n\\n, tr, \\n\\n\\n"');
                    }
                    for ( let j = 0; j < tr.length; i++) {
                        const td = (tr.querySelectorAll(`td:nth-child${j}`))
                        try {
                            pass
                        } catch (e) {
                            console.error('could not log "weeksElm"');
                        }
                    }
                } catch (e) {}
            }
        })
        console.log(persons);
    } catch (e){
        console.error("unable to get the work schedule \n unfortunately i still work");
    }
}




}
```

[image]

Comment: page.$$ selects all elements that match the selector, so you don't need to use a for loop. By the looks of your selector, I can see you don't have a lot of experience with selectors. Here's a useful site: https://devhints.io/css . I can't see the rest of the children, to recommend you a good selector. But should look something like this: "tbody .calendarCellRegularPast". A link to the page would be helpful.

Comment: @Invizi most of the children are visible in the one photo, I would link the site but it requires a login as it is a work scheduling site so it wouldn't really be possible, but I will check out that site, thanks a bunch!

Comment: @FiveFlyPaper if your main problem is only getting the spans with the class, you can try page.$$("tbody span.calendarCellRegularPast") . What does the element that has the date and time look like, btw?

Comment: I added a photo of the date and time to the bottom. The date is the calendarDateNormal and the time is in the span after `calendarCellRegularPast etmNoBorder`

Comment: Generally speaking, [images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) are not very helpful -- minimally, it's impractical to re-type it all to be able to execute code and play with it, almost always necessary to write a decent, accurate answer. You can show the HTML as a string, possibly with relevant JS to re-create the live page behavior and use `page.setContent(html)` to navigate to it, or provide a live link to the page. Also, rather than elements, what data are you ultimately trying to get? Thanks for the info.

Comment: A table within another table. Looks like fun.
Try ".etmCursor tr td". Then you can loop through them with .map and then use more selectors for each individual item you want. Such as ".calendarDateNormal" and ".CalendarCellRegularPast:nth-child(1)" and ".CalendarCellRegularPast:nth-child(2)".

Comment: @Invizi so how would I go about looping it with `.map`? when I do `page.$$('.etmCursor tr td');` I get all of the objects. Do I now want to pass them to `.map` with something like `const mapped = selectors.map()`

Comment: @FivePlyPaper It should look something like this: page.$$(".etmCursor tr td").map(parent => {
return {
date: "01",
start: "17:45",
end: "21:15"
}
}). You would replace the sudo values i made with selectors to the actual value.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I would recommend using a http client and cheerio.js for scraping, as it's faster and more lightweight. But I can understand why you would use puppeteer because of authentication.

You can get the html of the page using puppeteer by using `page.content()` and then pass that into cheerio. But if you wanted to do it using a http client, it would look like this:

```js
const axios = require("axios");
const cheerio = require("cheerio");

const PAGEURL = "example.com";

function getData() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    axios.get(PAGEURL).then(res => res.data).then(HTML => {
      const $ = cheerio.load(HTML);
      // scrape data here
      resolve()
    }).catch(err => reject(err));
  })
}
```

First, here's a mock-up of your HTML:

```html
<table class="etmSchedualTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="calanderCellRegularPast">
        <table class="etmCursor">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <span class="calanderDateNormal"> 01</span>
              </td>
              <td>
                <span class="calanderCellRegularPast etmNoBorder">                
                  <span>17:15</span> " - "
                  <span>23:45</span>
                  <span class="etmMoreLink">more...</span>
                </span>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <span class="calanderDateNormal"> 02</span>
              </td>
              <td>
                <span class="calanderCellRegularPast etmNoBorder">
                  <span>17:15</span> " - "
                  <span>23:45</span>
                  <span class="etmMoreLink">more...</span>
                </span>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

At the end, we want an array with objects that look like this:

```js
{
  date: 1,
  start: "17:45",
  end: "21:15"
}
```

To do so, we first need to select the parent that holds all the items we want. In this case it's $$(".etmCursor tbody tr"). This will give use a list of all the tr's in the table .etmCursor.

Now we have to loop through table rows (tr) and get the object properties.

```js
const timetable = $(".etmCursor tbody tr").map((i, elm) => {
  return {
    date: $(elm).find(".calendarDateNormal").text(),
    start: $(elm).find(".CalendarCellRegularPast:nth-child(1)").text(),
    end: $(elm).find(".CalendarCellRegularPast:nth-child(2)").text(),
  }
}).toArray();
```

The .map() method works in reverse to a normal map, where you get the element before the index. And since it uses a collection, we have to use toArray() to turn it to an array.

We use the .find() to do a search on the selected object.

.text() then gets use the text of that element.

Now we should have the data you wanted.

Comment: so I keep getting the error `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: page.$(...).map is not a function`. But what are you talking about with this cheerio thing? does it save a copy of the html and then just searches through that?

Comment: Like I could use `page.content()` to get html and then pass it to cheerio? Because I mean that could work as well

Comment: I don't mean to be a nuisance either but if you are free in the next few days to perhaps chat. I cant tell you know what you're doing but I can't give you the website as like I said it is login based

Comment: You would use page.content() to get the html of the page and replace HTML with page content `const $ = cheerio.load(await page.content())`. If you have more questions just ask.